# Writing waypoints to a file

Tags: c++

I have generated code which reads a file containing ways, take the individual waypoints and writes them into a new file, but only if the waypoint is not already present. At this moment my program stores the waypoint in a vector. Before the new found waypoint is written to the file the program checks if the waypoint is not already in the vector.

The program read and wrote the first 140,000 waypoint is 12 minutes, but as there are more then 13 million ways (expected 90 million waypoints) to read, examine and written this is going to take days.

I would much appreciate if anyone of you could give me a suggestion to improve the code.

```
struct NodeTemplate{
  string ID;
  string NodeID;     
  string latitude;
  string longitude;     
};
vector <NodeTemplate> NodesOut;

void split(const string& s, char c,
           vector<string>& v) {
   string::size_type i = 0;
   string::size_type j = s.find(c);

   while (j != string::npos) {
      v.push_back(s.substr(i, j-i));
      i = ++j;
      j = s.find(c, j);

      if (j == string::npos)
         v.push_back(s.substr(i, s.length()));
   }
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{     
      string filenameIn="ways.txt";
      ifstream myfile ((filenameIn).c_str( ));

      string fileNameNodes2="nodes2.txt";
      fstream myfile3;

      myfile3.open(fileNameNodes2.c_str(),fstream::out | fstream::trunc);
      myfile3.close();

      myfile3.open(fileNameNodes2.c_str(),fstream::out | fstream::app);


      if (myfile.is_open())
            {while ( getline (myfile,line1) )
                {   

                    string s1=line1;
                    vector<string> v1;
                    split(s1, ';', v1);

                    string s2=v1[4];
                    vector<string> v2;
                    split(s2, ',', v2);
                    for (int t=0;t<v2.size();t++)
                        {   
                            NodePresent=false;
                            for(int tt=0;tt<NodesOut.size();tt++)
                                { 
                                  if(atoi(v2[t].c_str())==atoi((NodesOut[tt].ID).c_str()))
                                    {   NodePresent=true;
                                        break;
                                    }
                            }


                                if(!NodePresent)
                                    {   
                                        stringstream ss;
                                        ss<<CounterLine;
                                        stringstream ss2;
                                        ss2<<v2[t];
                                        NewLine=ss.str()+";"+ss2.str()+"\n";
                                        myfile3.flush();
                                        myfile3<<NewLine;
                                        if(myfile3.fail()){cout<<"can't write...\n";}
                                        cout<<CounterLine<<"\r";
                                        CounterLine++;

                                        NodesOut.push_back(NodeTemplate());
                                        NodesOut[NodesOut.size()-1].ID=ss.str();
                                        NodesOut[NodesOut.size()-1].NodeID=ss2.str();


                                    }
                            }

                }
    }
  return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Comment: The time to search a vector for an object is O(n). If you keep the vector sorted it would be O(log(n)) (but at the cost of keeping it sorted). If you use a sorted container (std::map.  Tests are O(log(n)) and inserts are O(log(n)). (std::unordered_map. Tests are O(1) and inserts are O(1) but you pay for that in other ways).

Comment: Alternatively. You can load them all into memory sort and de-dup in one go then store them in a file. If your data is 100 bytes then 90,000,000 is approx 8G of memory. Quite doable on modern machines.

Comment: Personally I would think unique-efying a couple of million points should only take a couple of seconds (a min at the outside). But it would be nice to try can you post the data where we can download and try. Also would be interesting to note the structure of the data in the files. Treating everything as a string is a bad idea.

Answer (score 7):

### Structure

Hmm.
OK. Property bag so its OK

```
struct NodeTemplate{
  string ID;
  string NodeID;     
  string latitude;
  string longitude;     
};
```

But are lat/long really string? Would they not be numbers? Also ID sounds like a number type thing.

### Global Variables:

```
vector <NodeTemplate> NodesOut;
```

Global variables are bad. Don't do this.
They make the code hard to test. Side affects will cause problems.

### Prefer return over out parameters.

```
void split(const string& s, char c,
           vector<string>& v) {
```

Out parameters are hard to spot and maintian. Also its not very expensive to return a vector (there is no copy the compiler will elide it (assuming you enabled optimization)). Check out RVO and NRVO.

Also in C++11 and C++14 move semantics kick in and even if you can't optimize it with RVO or NRVO then it will be moved back to the calling function rather copied.

### Standard functions

A lot of this work made trivial by the standard functions and some lambda's

```
   while (j != string::npos) {
      v.push_back(s.substr(i, j-i));
      i = ++j;
      j = s.find(c, j);

      if (j == string::npos)
         v.push_back(s.substr(i, s.length()));
   }
}
```

How about:

```
// Use the string as a stream
std::stringstream stream(s);
// Copy "Item" objets from the stream into the vector.
std::copy(std::istream_iterator<Item<c>>(stream), std::istream_iterator<Item<c>>,
          std::back_inserter(v))
```

Not you can simply define an Item.

```
template<char c>
struct Item
{
    std::string   value;
    // Converts an Item into a string
    operator std::string const& {return value;}
    // Reads one item from the stream.
    friend std::istream& operator>>(std::istream& str, Item& data)
    {
        return std::genline(str, data.value, c);
    }
}
```

### Use constructors.

```
      string filenameIn="ways.txt";
      ifstream myfile ((filenameIn).c_str( ));
```

Much easier to write as:

```
      ifstream myfile("ways.txt");
```

Also C++11 allows you to construct the stream object with a std::string so you don't need to call `c_str()` if you really want to use the variable name.

I don't see the point of opening and closing the file to truncate it.

```
      myfile3.open(fileNameNodes2.c_str(),fstream::out | fstream::trunc);
      myfile3.close();

      myfile3.open(fileNameNodes2.c_str(),fstream::out | fstream::app);
```

By default a file will truncate an existing file. So all the above can be replaced by the single line:

```
      std::ofstream  myfile3("nodes2.txt");
```

This is a useless test:

```
      if (myfile.is_open())
```

I would be OK if you used it to generate an error message. But as it stands it is just protecting the `while` loop. You don't need to do that. The `while` loop will just not be entered because `getline()` will fail to read from an empty file.

As discussed above:

```
                    string s1=line1;   // usless copy.
                    vector<string> v1;
                    split(s1, ';', v1);
```

Much easier to write as:

```
                    vector<string> v1 = split(line1, ';');    
                    vector<string> v2 = split(v1[4], ',');
```

Though personally I would probably have written an input operator that read everything directly from the stream. Rather than copy strings all over the place.

#### Conversion is hurting.

```
 if(atoi(v2[t].c_str())==atoi((NodesOut[tt].ID).c_str()))
```

You are converting this every time!!!!!
You should convert it once when you read it in. Conversion is really expensive. (I mean the calls `atoi()`)

### Don't manually flush the stream

```
 myfile3.flush();
```

This will cause very inefficient use of the underlying buffer. Let the stream flush itself. It is much better at the job then you are.

## Better Soltion

This is how I would expect the code to be written.

```
class DataNode
{
     // Values 
     //   With the correct types NOT string
     friend std::istream& operator>>(std::istream& str, DataNode& data)
     {
          // read from the stream into a Data Node  "data".
          // Just one object.
          return str;
     }
     friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& str, DataNode const& data)
     {
          // Write the Data Node "data" to the stream.
          return str;
     }
}

int main()
{
    std::ifstream    input("inputfile");


    DataNode   data;
    std::unordered_set<DataNode>  dataNodes;

    while(input >> data) {
    {
        if (!dataNodes.find(data))
        {
            dataNodes.insert(std::move(data));
        }
    }

    std::ofstream    output("outputfile");
    std::copy(std::begin(dataNodes), std::end(dataNodes),
              std::ostream_iterator<DataNode>(output));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have found a rather simple solution which helped me to reduce the import time from days to only a couple of minutes. The big spender was checking the vector `NodesOut` every time to see if a node was already present or not.

By just replacing

```
                   NodePresent=false;
                    for(int tt=0;tt<NodesOut.size();tt++)
                        { 
                          if(atoi(v2[t].c_str())==atoi((NodesOut[tt].ID).c_str()))
                            {   NodePresent=true;
                                break;
                            }
                    }
```

with

```
NodePresent=false;
auto search = PresentNode.find(atoi(v2[t].c_str()));
if(search != PresentNode.end()) {
                                NodePresent=true;
}
```

and after finding a new waypoint:

```
PresentNode.insert(atoi(v2[t].c_str()));
```

the code now reads, checks and writes 90 million waypoints in just 3 minutes.

Comment: You don't say what type `PresentNode` is here. Presumably an `std::set` or `std::unordered_set`?